# Run @Before advice before @Around advice in Spring Boot AOP

Tags: spring-boot, spring-aop

I'm building a Spring Boot `v3.1.1` application and I want to use AOP to do certain things, for example, print logs to the console.

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface LogAround {}
```

With this custom annotation, I print to the console when the execution enters and exit from the method in my service.

```java
@LogAround
public String getName(@Long userId) {
   return "Lorem";
}

// Prints to console:
03:54PM INFO MyService : getName started.
03:55PM INFO MyService : getName finished.
```

*See implementation of the LogAround below.*

*The @LogAround is optional in my code and just a few methods has it.*

Now, I have the need of creating another advice to run on all methods (those who uses a custom execution annotation) to put some data to [MDC](https://www.baeldung.com/mdc-in-log4j-2-logback).

```java
// Pointcut expressions.
@Pointcut("execution(@UserIdRestricted * *(..))")
    public void userIdRestricted() {
}

@Pointcut("@annotation(LogAround)")
    public void logAround() {
}

// Pointcut signatures.
@Around("userIdRestricted()")
public Object verifyUserIdRestriction(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {}

@Around("logAround()")
public Object logAroundImpl(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
   Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringType());
   String methodName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();

   logger.info("{} started", methodName);

   Object proceed;
   try {
       proceed = joinPoint.proceed();
   } catch (Throwable ignored) {}

   logger.info("{} finished", methodName);

   return proceed;
}

// The new one
@Before("userIdRestricted()")
public void putUserIdToMdc(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
   log.info("putUserIdToMdc");
   MDC.put("userId", String.valueOf(1234));
}
```

The result of this in the console is:

```
03:54PM INFO MyService  : {} getName started. // <== It was run first and has no MDC data
03:54PM INFO AspectImpl : {} putUserIdToMdc
03:54PM INFO MyService  : {userId=1234} getName finished.
```

The advice `putUserIdToMdc()` is running after the `logAroundImpl()`. This means that the first log from `logAroundImpl()` won't have the MDC data.

*I'm not very skilled in the ways to configure an advice with some strange conditions.*

I have tried to find a way on another topics that let me describe this way of thinking:

- Run this advice, but if you encounter a `@LogAround`, then run this first.

No luck....

**How can I set the `putUserIdToMdc()` to run first?**

Thanks in advance and any help on this topic would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You have been around here vor 4+ years and should know how to ask a question. Your code does not even compile, and it also does not reproduce the problem. The aspect contains a superfluous `@Around("userIdRestricted()")` advice without even a return statement, no method with any `@UserIdRestricted` annotation, a logging advice which does not use `MDC.get("userId")`. Next time, prepare a proper [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and run it in your IDE before copying & pasting. Editing code after pasting is bad practice, the result is just pseudo code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did **your** job by fixing and amending your fragmentary code, which was quite a bit of work, just to be able to reproduce the situation and offer a solution.

Please read the Spring manual chapter on [Advice Ordering](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/aop/ataspectj/advice.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering) in order to understand my answer better.

The gist of it is that you need to split your aspect into two separate aspects, each one doing one thing only. Then use `@Order` to determine which aspects have higher or lower precedence.

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q76700254;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface LogAround {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q76700254;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface UserIdRestricted {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q76700254;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyComponent {
  @LogAround
  @UserIdRestricted
  public String getName(Long userId) {
    return "Lorem";
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q76700254;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.MDC;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
@Order(2)
public class LogAspect {
  @Pointcut("@annotation(LogAround)")
  public void logAround() {}

  @Around("logAround()")
  public Object logAroundImpl(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringType());
    String methodName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
    logger.info("{} {} started", MDC.get("userId"), methodName);
    Object proceed = null;
    try {
      proceed = joinPoint.proceed();
    }
    catch (Throwable ignored) {}
    logger.info("{} {} finished", MDC.get("userId"), methodName);
    return proceed;
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q76700254;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.MDC;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
@Order(1)
public class UserIdAspect {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserIdAspect.class);

  @Pointcut("execution(@UserIdRestricted * *(..))")
  public void userIdRestricted() {}

  @Before("userIdRestricted()")
  public void putUserIdToMdc() {
    log.info("putUserIdToMdc");
    MDC.put("userId", String.valueOf(1234));
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q76700254;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class DemoApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args)) {
      System.out.println(context.getBean(MyComponent.class).getName(123L));
    }
  }
}
```

Console log:

```
... d.s.spring.q76700254.DemoApplication     : Started DemoApplication in 6.241 seconds (JVM running for 7.431)
... d.s.spring.q76700254.UserIdAspect        : putUserIdToMdc
... d.s.spring.q76700254.MyComponent         : 1234 getName started
... d.s.spring.q76700254.MyComponent         : 1234 getName finished
Lorem
```

Comment: Thank you very much for supporting my question and your help presenting a solution. I had read the documentation that you present, but the intention was to think of a way to perform the need from a pointcut expression. Perhaps the way of describing the question was not ideal. In the same way, seeing your example and how easy it is, I decided to go that way and try not to reinvent the wheel. About the MVCE, I tried to express the basic idea, I didn't think it was important for this case. I will take that into account next time, thanks for your observation. Very nice example by the way!.